# "Compartir" addEventListener JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom

estoy aprendiendo javascript y queria saber si es posible hacer esto

tengo una tabla de puntajes donde hay 4 jugadores, cada jugador ingresa su puntajes a travez de un datalist, en el javascript hize los eventos 
y queria saber si hay una forma de compartir los eventos entre los jugadores ya que los datos del js son todos los mismos. Osea puedo hacer esto creando variables y copiando y pegando, cambiandole algunas cosas, pero queria saber si hay alguna alternativa.

aca ingreso una parte del html y js para que se entienda

```
var uno = document.getElementsByName("unoSeis") [0];
var dos = document.getElementsByName("unoSeis") [1];
var tres = document.getElementsByName("unoSeis") [2];

uno.addEventListener('input',function(){
    if (this.value =="Uno"){
        uno.value=mostrar.value=total=1; 
    }else if(this.value =="Dos"){
        uno.value=mostrar.value=total= 2;
    }else if(this.value =="Tres"){
        uno.value=mostrar.value=total= 3;
    }else if(this.value =="Cuatro"){
        uno.value=mostrar.value=total= 4;
    }else if(this.value =="Cinco"){
        uno.value=mostrar.value=total= 5;
    }else{
        uno.value="X";
        total=0;
    }
});
dos.addEventListener('input',function(){
    if (this.value =="Uno"){
        dos.value=mostrar.value=total=parseInt(2+total);
    }else if(this.value =="Dos"){
        dos.value=mostrar.value=total=parseInt(4+total);
    }else if(this.value =="Tres"){
        dos.value=mostrar.value=total=parseInt(6+total);
    }else if(this.value =="Cuatro"){
        dos.value=mostrar.value=total=parseInt(8+total);
    }else if(this.value =="Cinco"){
        dos.value=mostrar.value=total=parseInt(10+total);
    }else{
        //pongo el +0 ya que si no hay un valor en el 1 
(aunque deberia haberlo) como total tira error
        mostrar.value=total=parseInt(total+0);
        dos.value="X";
    }
});
```

aca el html

```html
<datalist id="puntaje1a6">
          <option value="Uno">
          <option value="Dos">
          <option value="Tres">
          <option value="Cuatro">
          <option value="Cinco">
          <option value="Tachar">
 </datalist>

<h2>Jugador 1</h2>
<div class="celdas"><input list="puntaje1a6" name="unoSeis" ></div>
            <div class="celdas"><input list="puntaje1a6"  name="unoSeis" ></div>
            <div class="celdas"><input list="puntaje1a6" name="unoSeis" ></div>

<h2>Jugador 2</h2>
<div class="celdas"><input list="puntaje1a6"></div>
            <div class="celdas"><input list="puntaje1a6"  ></div>
            <div class="celdas"><input list="puntaje1a6" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear un bucle para que todos tus `inputs` tengan el mismo código al evento 'input'

Te dejo un ejemplo documentado

```js
// Primero crea una lista de los elementos que necesitas, en este caso los inputs que se tengan el atributo name="foo"
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="foo"]');

//Recorre los inputs
inputs.forEach( (input) => {
  
  //Agregales el evento
  input.addEventListener('input', function(){
  
    // Crea aquí tu código
    const value = this.value;
    console.log( value );
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="foo">
<input type="text" name="foo">
<input type="text" name="foo">
```

También puedes hacer una función general y asignarla directo al evento del `input`

```js
const inputFunction = ( that ) => {
  console.log( that.value );
};
```

```html
<input type="text" name="bar" oninput="inputFunction(this)">
<input type="text" name="bar" oninput="inputFunction(this)">
<input type="text" name="bar" oninput="inputFunction(this)">
```

Todo depende de lo que pretendas hacer y todos tus inputs hagan lo mismo, si alguno hace algo diferente tendrás que fragmentar tu código. Llegar al objetivo es fácil. Espero te puedas guiar con esto.

Comment: Entendi mejor el primero, lo unico que cambiaria de input seria el lugar donde muestra el dato x ejemplo el jugador 1 muestra el total en un visor1 y el jugador 2 en un visor2 , eso es posible o si o si tengo q crear otro input? porque probe haciendolo con ese codigo y los datos del j2 reemplazan los del j1 . nose si se quedo claro, pero algo asi me pasa https://imgur.com/a/1SU1UHJ